# Swagger ui in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, api, swagger, swagger-ui

I installed

```
gem 'swagger-docs'
gem 'swagger-ui_rails'
```

Then provided some documentation from the sample

```
swagger_controller :users, "User Management"

swagger_api :index do
    summary "Fetches all User items"
    notes "This lists all the active users"
    param :query, :page, :integer, :optional, "Page number"
    param :path, :nested_id, :integer, :optional, "Team Id"
    response :unauthorized
    response :not_acceptable, "The request you made is not acceptable"
    response :requested_range_not_satisfiable
  end
```

I created `ApiController` and in `index.html.erb` added rendering as partial view for swagger.

```
<h1>hello</h1>

<% discovery_url = Rails.root + '/api/v1/api-docs.json' %>
<%= render partial: 'swagger_ui/swagger_ui', locals: {discovery_url: discovery_url} %>
```

It renders only main page of swagger without colors or colored containers, but nothing works, if I try to click on any button nothing happens.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the .js and .css files for swagger-ui. Follow the instructions at https://github.com/d4be4st/swagger-ui_rails in the README, under "usage". In short, you need to modify your application.js to include the swagger-ui file:

```
//= require swagger-ui
```

and modify application.css to include the stylesheet

```
*= require swagger-ui
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your partial with a `<div class="swagger-section">`